# Karate - Is there a way where I can use a variable in string regex

Tags: karate

Karate - Is there a way where I can use a variable in string regex. Something similar as below

```
match each productCodes == "#regex (?i).*+codes+.*"
```

Any alternative or best practice would be appreciated. I am trying to get an string array from response for doing a match each (which gives me a string at a time) and compare to a string variable coming from another call.

Comment: I don't understand at all. please provide a better example

Comment: The following link should help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/README.md#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: I just want to understand if I can pass a variable in regex in place of string.

As per documentation, below is the format-

#regex STR Expects actual (string) value to match the regular-expression 'STR'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: Regex Match

Scenario: 
    * def act = ["abcd","bcde","cdef","defg"]
    * def exp = "c"
    * match each act == ('#regex (?i).*' + exp +'.*')
```

Related link: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/README.md#enclosed-javascript